# python+cx_oracle can not parse "connect by" syntax

Tags: python-3.6, cx-oracle, dbeaver

I wonder why my query result is different between oracle client (I use `DBeaver 7.1`) and python+cx_oracle when I use `connect by` syntax to get date list of TUESDAY in current month, belows are my code, any help will be thankful.

### oracle

```sql
SELECT 
    ROWNUM AS ID,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYYMMDD') AS MDATE
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE) dt FROM dual)
WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'DY') IN ('TUE')
CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'MM') = TRUNC(DT, 'MM')
```

the result is:

```
| ID | MDATE    |
|----|----------|
| 1  | 20200707 |
| 2  | 20200714 |
| 3  | 20200721 |
| 4  | 20200728 |
```

### python

```py
In[1]: import cx_Oracle
In[2]: cursor = cx_Oracle.connection('id', 'pw', 'port', 'dsn').cursor()
In[3]: sql = """
    SELECT 
        ROWNUM AS ID,
        TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYYMMDD') AS MDATE
    FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE) dt FROM dual)
    WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'DY') IN ('TUE')
    CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(DT, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'MM') = TRUNC(DT, 'MM')
"""

In[4]: cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
Out[4]: []
```

### requirements

```
cx-Oracle==7.3.0
python=3.6.8
```

Comment: Not connected to the same DB?  Data not committed?

Comment: connect to the same DB, but no data return by cx_oracle

Comment: I just tried your code. It works just fine. :-) You've got something else going on that's causing problems -- but what that is, I have no idea!